# video clip no longer plays (autorelease issue)

Tags: xcode4, mpmovieplayercontroller, autorelease

I took care of a memory leak related to the alloc object, however I think I have fouled up my code as now my video clip does not play. I believe that I have caused the device to release before the clip starts. Could someone help me to rearrange my code? I would be greatly appreciative of a few hints to get playback working again. Here is a sample of what I am working with.

```
@implementation ELECTRIC_GROOVEYViewController

-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender
{
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1960" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController =
[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL]autorelease];     
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

[[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                               object:nil];
// no moviecontrolls
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
// looping forever
moviePlayerController.repeatMode= MPMovieRepeatModeOne;


[moviePlayerController play];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are `autorelease`ing the `moviePlayerController` object. It has no further retention. Hence the object must be getting deallocated. Maintain a reference to it by creating an instance variable and release it after you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Deepak. However when I input my code for instance variable I am recieving error. Build does complete though my video clip still does not play despite making the instance reference. Could you illustrate what i may be doing wrong using my code above. I really appreciate your help in this.

Comment: @Jay, sorry for not noticing this earlier, did you get this resolved?